# Complexheatmap row-names not showing up

Tags: r, graphics, complexheatmap

I'm not sure what Im doing wrong since I have used the code many times before the row names doesn't show up although that is assigned to in my code.

I have tried putting the row-name both left and right side but it still doesn't show up

```
heat <- t(scale(t(df[,3:ncol(df)])))

head(heat)

rownames(heat) <- df$Gene
ColAnn <- data.frame(colnames(heat))
Sample = c(rep("ACE2_MOCK",1),rep("ACE2_IRGM_KO_MOCK",1))

anno <- as.data.frame(Sample)
categories <- data.frame(anno)
colnames(anno) <- c("Condition")
ColAnn <- HeatmapAnnotation(df=anno,which="col", col=list(Condition=c("ACE2_MOCK"="black","ACE2_IRGM_KO_MOCK"="red")))


RowAnn <- data.frame(df$Family)
colnames(RowAnn) <- c("Gene family")
colours <- list("Gene family"=c("Diff_gene" = "white"))


RowAnn <- HeatmapAnnotation(df=RowAnn, col=colours, which="row")
boxAnnCol <- HeatmapAnnotation(boxplot=anno_boxplot(heat, border=TRUE, gp=gpar(fill="#CCCCCC"), 
                                                    pch=".", size=unit(2, "mm"), 
                                                    axis=TRUE,  axis_param = list(side = "left")), 
                               annotation_width=unit(c(1, 6.5), "cm"))




myCol <- colorRampPalette(c("navyblue", "white", "red"))(100)
myBreaks <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, length.out=100)
myBreaks
hmap <- Heatmap(heat,
                name="Z-score",
                col=colorRamp2(myBreaks, myCol),
                #heatmap_legend_param=list(color_bar="continuous", 
                #                         legend_direction="vertical", legend_width=unit(5,"cm"),
                #                        title_position="lefttop", title_gp=gpar(fontsize=10, fontface="bold")),
                
                #Split heatmap rows by gene family
                #split=df$Family,
                #split = NULL,
                #km = 4,
                #row_split = 7, 
                #row_km = 4, 
                #row_km_repeats = 100,
                #row_title = "cluster_%s",
                #row_title_gp = gpar(col = c("red", "blue","green","yellow","navyblue","violet","pink"), font = 1:2),
                row_gap = unit(0, "mm"),
                border = FALSE,
                #Row annotation configurations
                cluster_rows=TRUE,
                show_row_dend=TRUE,
                row_dend_side = "left",
                #row_title="Transcript", #overridden by 'split' it seems
                #row_title_side="left",
                #row_title_gp=gpar(fontsize=8,fontface="bold"),
                #row_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 8),
                show_row_names=TRUE,
                row_names_side="right",
                row_title_rot=0,
                
                #Column annotation configuratiions
                cluster_columns=FALSE,
                show_column_dend=FALSE,
                column_title="Samples",
                column_title_side="top",
                column_title_gp=gpar(fontsize=10, fontface="bold"),
                column_title_rot=0,
                column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 20, fontface="bold"),
                show_column_names=TRUE,
                
                #Dendrogram configurations: columns
                clustering_distance_columns="euclidean",
                clustering_method_columns="complete",
                column_dend_height=unit(10,"mm"),
                
                #Dendrogram configurations: rows
                #clustering_distance_rows="euclidean",
                clustering_distance_rows = "pearson",
                clustering_method_rows="complete",
                row_dend_width=unit(15,"mm"),
                
                #top_annotation_height=unit(0.5,"cm"),
                top_annotation=ColAnn,
                
                #bottom_annotation_height=unit(2, "cm"),
                bottom_annotation=boxAnnCol)

hmap + RowAnn
```

What i get is this
[image: plot]

My dataframe used for this plot

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Family = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), class = "factor", .Label = "Diff_gene"), 
    gene = c("Apobec1", "Apobec3", "Bst2", "Ddx58", "Ddx60", 
    "Gbp10", "Gbp11", "Gbp2", "Gbp2b", "Gbp3", "Gbp4", "Gbp5", 
    "Gbp6", "Gbp7", "Gbp8", "Gbp9", "Irf4", "Irf7", "Irf9", "Irgm2", 
    "Isg15", "Isg20", "Oas1a", "Oas1b", "Oas1c", "Oas1e", "Oas1g", 
    "Oas2", "Oas3", "Oasl1", "Oasl2", "Ifi203", "Ifi204", "Ifi205", 
    "Ifi207", "Ifi209", "Ifi213", "Ifi214", "Ifi27", "Ifi27l2a", 
    "Ifi27l2b", "Ifi35", "Ifi44", "Ifih1", "Ifit1", "Ifit1bl1", 
    "Ifit2", "Ifit3", "Ifit3b", "Ifitm3", "Zbp1", "Znfx1"), ACE2_MOCK = c(407.098476061909, 
    1855.94866662715, 2902.87979118331, 1418.48768158987, 307.715152670574, 
    5.30325977271867, 16.6258275641314, 1916.43808451318, 5.37642563822957, 
    1186.2316535435, 1335.58823779077, 305.17848295847, 99.1645827545343, 
    1757.32851199409, 194.008799582845, 1174.68142359132, 83.0351252864635, 
    922.102271319543, 1996.60775743498, 1367.83617562333, 759.423540077501, 
    1037.56327181345, 232.674297494372, 259.571063835334, 150.719320562386, 
    5.072582464476, 71.359745330416, 567.465294501395, 89.6946379260825, 
    126.119036502863, 1731.68835553741, 1646.65814253949, 138.75431484587, 
    141.116325067812, 235.494888533203, 347.710689734509, 618.098320219156, 
    11.9744562091738, 3747.04713625385, 2177.4137837713, 5.68707745603433, 
    2088.56348903007, 413.345543446159, 866.822832248851, 1486.09638215541, 
    155.425497292957, 528.828483791686, 1806.34726472835, 320.853994579289, 
    8210.82040783904, 238.780701171051, 1938.47023785919), ACE2_IRGM_KO_MOCK = c(749.181940759016, 
    2993.70562800799, 8793.06507227506, 2935.66672238197, 1231.25630555463, 
    57.7973443352929, 115.653747983434, 5552.3040666907, 16.8963656095157, 
    5055.50008201252, 3567.50362240923, 1424.18048056808, 457.870814791012, 
    4116.74672827908, 590.42192220289, 2867.08788857983, 220.517543547042, 
    9912.18439436293, 4141.65152832592, 4971.031140377, 4857.80714988756, 
    1740.4008718546, 1866.34498107905, 963.651479352654, 300.823456034431, 
    24.4027803221429, 797.901766740012, 5978.13674870163, 1334.9339760727, 
    1044.86971880756, 9272.23976035301, 4408.89883189086, 893.614402712474, 
    349.75618607996, 626.559122115524, 1115.7496625029, 1889.66443188002, 
    80.1402404741233, 6663.17351139748, 13444.1443794422, 11.7830381943685, 
    3290.74444153149, 2713.19509099661, 2395.30081346767, 8963.21424851447, 
    514.633361828127, 2452.5798999775, 11824.1253276475, 1987.20950755614, 
    19271.4840719139, 2304.28156105082, 4325.00175274422)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-52L))
```

My session info

```
 sessionInfo()
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] cluster_2.1.3        circlize_0.4.14      ComplexHeatmap_2.0.0 dplyr_1.0.8          readxl_1.4.0        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rstudioapi_0.13     magrittr_2.0.3      hms_1.1.1           tidyselect_1.1.2    clue_0.3-60         colorspace_2.0-3    rjson_0.2.20       
 [8] R6_2.5.1            rlang_1.0.2         fansi_1.0.3         tools_3.6.0         parallel_3.6.0      png_0.1-7           utf8_1.2.2         
[15] cli_3.2.0           DBI_1.1.2           ellipsis_0.3.2      assertthat_0.2.1    tibble_3.1.6        lifecycle_1.0.1     crayon_1.5.1       
[22] RColorBrewer_1.1-3  purrr_0.3.4         readr_2.1.2         tzdb_0.3.0          GlobalOptions_0.1.2 vctrs_0.4.1         shape_1.4.6        
[29] glue_1.6.2          compiler_3.6.0      pillar_1.7.0        cellranger_1.1.0    generics_0.1.2      GetoptLong_1.0.5    pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

Any suggestion or help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If I'm reading this right, you're giving the heatmap `heat` as data. Doesn't `t()` from the line where you created `heat` occasionally strip rownames and colnames?

Comment: yes that is correct..

Comment: @Jeff "occasionally strip rownames and colnames" is this the reason for row-names issue?